INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY inserting MD custom Objects via API
I have an issue inserting master detail related custom objects via API.
I have 2 custom Objects : SalesOrder (Master) and SalesOrderItem (detail), in SalesOrderItem I create the field Order__c with Data Type Master-Detail(Sales Order)
Master-Detail Options are:
Related To                  : Sales Order
Related List Label          : Order Items
Sharing Setting Read/Write  : Allows users with at least Read/Write access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.
Child Relationship Name     : Order_Items

I try to insert new order with 2 Salesforce API :

Composite tree with this example body
{
"records": [
{
"attributes": {
"type": "SalesOrder__c",
"referenceId": "Order1"
},
"Account__c": "0011j00001yeNG1AAM",
"BillingAddressCode__c": "8lWMB0000001qXA2AY",
"ShippingAddressCode__c": "8lWMB0000001qXA2AY",
"DeliveryType__c": "UPS",
"Distributor__c": "0011i00001TkVhOAAV",
"RecordTypeId": "0121j000006HWFGAA4",
"Status__c": "Closed",
"Order_Items__r": {
"records": [
{
"attributes": {
"type": "SalesOrderItem__c",
"referenceId": "refOrderItem1"
},
"ItemNumber__c": 1,
"OrderItemStatus__c": "Confirmed",
"Product__c": "01tSY000003qIyQYAU",
"Quantity__c": 1
}
]
}
}
]
}

Composite dependent with this example body
{
"allOrNone":true
,"collateSubrequests":false
,"compositeRequest":[
{
"method":"POST"
,
"referenceId":"refNewOrder"
,"url":"/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/SalesOrder__c"
,"body":{
"Account__c":"0011j00001yeNG1AAM"
,"BillingAddressCode__c":"8lWMB0000001qXA2AY"
,"ShippingAddressCode__c":"8lWMB0000001qXA2AY"
,"DeliveryType__c":"UPS"
,"Distributor__c":"0011i00001TkVhOAAV"
,"RecordTypeId":"0121j000006HWFGAA4"
}
}
,{
"method":"POST"
,"referenceId":"refNewOrderItem1"
,"url":"/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/SalesOrderItem__c"
,"body":{
"Order__c":"@{refNewOrder.id}"
,"ItemNumber__c":1
,"OrderItemStatus__c":"Confirmed"
,"Product__c":"01tSY000003qIyQYAU"
,"Quantity__c":11
,"Reason__c":"Free"
,"SalesPrice__c":0
}
}
]
}


In both cases if I try to insert only the order no errors is raised but with rows the error is:

{"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"referenceId":"refOrderItem1","errors":[{"statusCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY","message":"insufficient
access rights on cross-reference id: 01tSY000003qIyQ","fields":[]}]}]}

I am struggling with profiles, roles and permission sets but I can't figure it out were my mistake is.
Any help or suggestion that poitn me in the right direction will be very appreciated.

01tSY000003qIyQ is your Product2 record, so you need to verify the integration user has the correct object and sharing permissions to the Product2 object.  Please [edit] your post to include details on the integration user and the permission set / sharing rules config.

@David Cheng : thanks for the answer but in this specific example my product is 01tSY000003qIyQYAU. I'm successfully using several API to manage sObjects in Salesforce including Product2, so I don't think this issue is due to Product2 permissions. In addition I try using different IDs but the error message mentions always the same (01tSY000003qIyQ).
